# How to install multiple version of GCC (GCC-3.3) on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, gcc

I am not familiar with Ubuntu and I want to install old version (3.3) of `gcc` to compile some code. When I tried with

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-3.3
```

it's not installing.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-3.3
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-3.3-hppa64' for regex 'gcc-3.3'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gfortran-5 libamd2.4.1 libbtf1.2.1 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcholmod3.0.6 libcsparse3.1.4 libcxsparse3.1.4 libgfortran-5-dev
  libklu1.3.3 libldl2.2.1 libspqr2.0.2 libumfpack5.7.1 openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

When I tried to list all the available versions of `gcc`,

```
 sudo apt-cache search gcc
```

it's not listing `gcc` 3.3. How do I install gcc 3.3 on my Ubuntu?

My current `gcc` version is:

```
~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `gcc` 3.3 is ancient. You will probably need to rebuild it from scratch on your system, assuming that's even possible. A binary might install, though probably won't. Are you sure a more recent version of gcc won't work for you?

Comment: I got debian repository and added it to /etc/apt/sources.list. It works for me

Answer (score 2):

**download, compile, and install GCC from source**

i typically get the `tar.gz` one;
you can get the source from one of the mirror sites listed from gcc.gnu.org
https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html

```
tar -xf gcc-3.3.6.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-3.3.6
make
make install
```

adjust "--prefix=`/usr/local/gcc-3.3.6`" accordingly; i prefer to be explicit it makes things easier knowing where everything is.  I think if not specified it will default to `/usr/local/bin`

you can do a `./configure --help` to get a description of all the options available;  `prefix=` is simply where it will get installed when doing `make install` and will also tell of the default install location if "prefix=" is not specified.

when using `--prefix=` you then need to supersede this local installation of whatever you did in your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables like this

```
*for bash*
export PATH=/usr/local/gcc-3.3.6/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-3.3.6/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

*for csh or tcsh*
setenv PATH /usr/local/gcc-3.3.6/bin:${PATH}
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/gcc-3.3.6/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

either open a new terminal window or first type `rehash`

then a `which gcc` will let you know the version of gcc you would be using without manually and explictly having to do `/usr/local/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc` to use it.

**whenever running executables later on that have been compiled with a newer/older version of GCC make sure your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is correctly set to that corresponding GCC version.**

during the `./configure` step that will let you know if you are missing prerequisites so don't be alarmed if this step isn't 100% successful on first try, you will either need to download and install them or disable them by looking it up from the output of `./configure --help`

- this way you can have multiple gcc versions to your heart's content, keep each gcc install separate using `--prefix=`
- adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `PATH`, accordingly to use whichever

Answer (score 1):

You can download the debian package from here

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/gcc-3.3_3.3.6-15ubuntu6_i386.deb

and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package
```

Comment: There are two folders when I downloaded package from this link, DEBIAN and usr. Which path should I give?

Comment: This link will download the `.deb` file. Use the path to the `.deb` package. Don't extract it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Launchpad has recent builds of gcc 3.3 available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-3.3). I don't know if this is recent enough to work, but I suppose it's worth a try.

If you need further elaboration, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've added Debian repository to /etc/apt/source.

```
    deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
```

Then I searched gcc by using

```
sudo apt-cache search gcc
```

Then it listed gcc-3.3
then I installed

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-3.3 g++-3.3
```

Then I've changed the symbolic link of gcc to select gcc 3.3

Comment: Are you able to switch between `gcc-3` and `gcc-5`?